Screen goes completely dark after boot menu (after installing full-disk encryption)
My goal: install Ubuntu Desktop with full disk encryption (lvm or zfs) on an Asus NUC 14 Pro+ (Ubuntu IDs it as NUC14RVS-B with Intel Core Ultra 7 155H CPU).
What works: Installing Ubuntu without full disk encryption, using the same LiveCD and hardware.
What doesn't work: Booting up (post bootloader) after having installed full-disk encrypted Ubuntu. Screen goes black (completely, no cursor, no purple etc).
I have a LiveCD usb with ubuntu-24.04.1-desktop-amd64 (checked for correct checksum).
The LiveCD boots just fine and allows me to install (unencrypted) Ubuntu via the default settings (install third party/media codecs checked) and "erase everything" option. It finishes and boots fine after reboot.
If I do the same thing again and select the default option but only change to "advanced options" Full Disk Encryption (ZFS or LVM has same problem) the installation finishes with an OK message. After restart and remove the liveCD I am shown a boot menu with Ubuntu at the top but when I select it the screen just turns dark (but computer seems to be running still). The same thing happen if I select Ubuntu Advanced Options and boot into the Recovery Mode.
If I boot into the LiveCD again I can decrypt the drive just fine and mount it.
Gparted shows me the LiveCD has created three partitions on disk. fat32 /boot/efi (boot, esp flag), ext4 /boot and [Encrypted] on /.
The display is an Apple Studio Display connected via thunderbolt if that matters.
I have turned off SecureBoot and allowed 3rd party UEFI in the BIOS.
I have tried editing grub to boot it with nomodeset nouveau.modeset=0 i915.modeset=0 but no luck.
Any suggestions for what I should try next?
EDIT Narrowed down the issue further, it only happens when booting  with the Studio Display over thunderbolt connected. Connected it to another display with HDMI and that boots up well with no issues.

It's gotta be a driver issue.  Something about your encryption is preventing the driver from loading.  I'd suspect a secure boot issue, but you think you've turned that off so....dunno.

When the screen goes dark, does it continue to boot off you blindly enter the decryption passphrase?

Yes, seems it does (I can tell by entering password it starts making a lot of fan noise so guessing it booting), but the screen never turns on.
Another thing that works: Plugin in hdmi screen and boot. Then connect the Studio Display after boot (I can even disconnect the HDMI at this point and the studio display continue working).

Managed to resolve the issue:
The problem was that the firmware for the thunderbolt display was not loaded before decryption.
I resolved this by the following steps:
sudo vim /etc/initramfs-tools/modules

and added
i915
thunderbolt

then
sudo update-initramfs -u

Next reboot the screen displayed the decryption prompt as expected!
